# Google Chrome missing right double border

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I had some (what I thought was fairly simple, vanilla) HTML + CSS like this (omitting irrelevant parts):

CSS:

```css
.firstcol {border-bottom: solid 1px #666666; border-right: solid 1px #666666;}
.secondcol {border-bottom: solid 1px #666666;}
```

HTML:

```
<table style="BORDER: #666666 2px solid; border-collapse: collapse;">
```

(all the `<td>`s are class either *firstcol* or *secondcol*)

The net effect is a table with double outer border and single inner border.  It works fine on IE and Firefox, but in Chrome the right side double border of the table is missing.  Only the right side.  It gets the top, bottom, and left.

Is this unsound code, or just an obscure Chrome bug?

Comment: Can't see any difference between Chrome and IE in [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/ERV5q/) - do you see any difference? If not, the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: OK, turns out that Chrome is not forgiving of an excessive colspan value on one row (greater than the maximum number of cols on any row).  Other browsers don't mind, but Chrome omits the right-side border in that case.

Comment: Can you add that to the fiddle so it's reproduced?

Comment: It's here: [excessive colspan](http://jsfiddle.net/ERV5q/13/)

Comment: Interesting! Well, you can always use JavaScript to fix wrong colspan.. other than that can't see any way around this.

Comment: Now that I know, I can just correct it.  It comes from cloning the same table over and over for different content, and not bothering to reduce the colspan for tables that happen to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Recoded and.... added a workaround, simply forcing 2px border on right side of last column:

```
td:last-of-type
{
    border-right-width:2px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ERV5q/19/)

I admit that is a very strange Chrome bug.